# How to configure vim/nvim on ubuntu 18.04 for c# .net-core development with autocompletion

Tags: c#, vim, .net-core, neovim, ubuntu-18.04

I have ubuntu 18.04 machine with .net-core 2.0.0 installed.
I also have (neovim)nvim v0.2.2 installed.

I am able to build and run .net-core projects on my ubuntu machine.
My question is how can I use vim/nvim with c# autocompletion for my .net-core projects.
I have installed Omnisharp-vim plugin for my nvim and it's not working.
I tried to configure omnisharp-roslyn but no luck. I read on the Omnisharp github page that i need omnisharp-roslyn server installed for Omnisharp-vim to work. Unforunately no luck.
I have seen people coding c# in vim with autocompletion on youtube.

Any idea how to setup ? because I would love to have this functionality on my ubuntu machine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use without any problem. See my config for C#:

```
" C#
Plug 'https://github.com/adelarsq/vim-csharp', {'for':['cs','csx','cshtml.html','csproj','solution']}
Plug 'https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vim', {'for':['cs','csx','cshtml.html','csproj','solution'], 'on': ['OmniSharpInstall']}

let g:OmniSharp_server_stdio = 1
let g:OmniSharp_selector_ui = ''       " Use vim - command line, quickfix etc.
let g:OmniSharp_highlight_types = 2

augroup my_omnisharp
    autocmd!
    au FileType cs nmap <buffer> <silent> ga :OmniSharpGetCodeActions<CR>
    au FileType cs nmap <buffer> <silent> gd :OmniSharpGotoDefinition<CR>
    au FileType cs nmap <buffer> <silent> gq :OmniSharpCodeFormat<CR>
    au FileType cs nmap <buffer> <silent> gu :OmniSharpFixUsings<CR>
    au FileType cs nmap <buffer> <silent> gr :OmniSharpFindUsages<CR>
    au FileType cs nmap <buffer> <silent> gK :OmniSharpDocumentation<CR>
    au FileType cs nmap <buffer> <silent> <F2> :OmniSharpRename<CR>
augroup END
```